# Black screen after closing Admob Banner Ad

Tags: android, opengl-es, admob

I just finished the Super Jumper tutorial (from Beginning Android Games By Mario Zechner) some days ago and I was trying to add Admob to the game.

I followed the guide that google offers (using google-play-services_lib) and everything seemed to work fine until I clicked one of the development Ads.

The Ad opens as expected, but when I close it to return to the Game my Game is black. An ANR occurs if I touch the screen, and if I force close the App the Game restarts...

I discovered that onDestroy is called when I open the Ad and that a new instance of the game is created (onCreate is called), I guess that's why the Game restarts after I force close the App.

I don't know why this happens, but I tried running the game on a different smartphone and I got the same result.

Here is my code I use:

```
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.example.jumper.framework.Audio;
import com.example.jumper.framework.FileIO;
import com.example.jumper.framework.Game;
import com.example.jumper.framework.Input;
import com.example.jumper.framework.Screen;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public abstract class GLGame extends Activity implements Game, Renderer {
    enum GLGameState {
        Initialized,
        Running,
        Paused,
        Finished,
        Idle
    }

    GLSurfaceView glView;    
    GLGraphics glGraphics;
    Audio audio;
    Input input;
    FileIO fileIO;
    Screen screen;

    AdView adView;
    AdRequest adRequest;
    private static String AD_UNIT_ID = "MY_ID_HERE";
    GLGameState state = GLGameState.Initialized;
    Object stateChanged = new Object();
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    WakeLock wakeLock;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        glView.setRenderer(this);

        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
        //adView.setAdListener(new AdListenerPage(this));
        adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.addView(glView);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
           new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);


        layout.addView(adView, params);
        setContentView(layout);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("MY_DEVICE_HERE").build());

        glGraphics = new GLGraphics(glView);
        fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(getAssets());
        audio = new AndroidAudio(this);
        input = new AndroidInput(this, glView, 1, 1);
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "GLGame");       
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        glView.onResume();
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {       
        glGraphics.setGL(gl);

        synchronized(stateChanged) {
            if(state == GLGameState.Initialized)
                screen = getStartScreen();
            state = GLGameState.Running;
            screen.resume();
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {       
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {               
        GLGameState state = null;

        synchronized(stateChanged) {
            state = this.state;
        }

        if(state == GLGameState.Running) {
            float deltaTime = (System.nanoTime()-startTime) / 1000000000.0f;
            startTime = System.nanoTime();

            screen.update(deltaTime);
            screen.present(deltaTime);
        }

        if(state == GLGameState.Paused) {
            screen.pause();           
            synchronized(stateChanged) {
                this.state = GLGameState.Idle;
                stateChanged.notifyAll();
            }
        }

        if(state == GLGameState.Finished) {
            screen.pause();
            screen.dispose();
            synchronized(stateChanged) {
                this.state = GLGameState.Idle;
                stateChanged.notifyAll();
            }           
        }
    }   

    @Override
    public void onPause() {       
        synchronized(stateChanged) {
            if(isFinishing())           
                state = GLGameState.Finished;
            else
                state = GLGameState.Paused;
            while(true) {
                try {
                    stateChanged.wait();
                    break;
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {         
                }
            }
        }
        wakeLock.release();
        glView.onPause(); 
        super.onPause();
    }   

    @Override
    public Input getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    @Override
    public FileIO getFileIO() {
        return fileIO;
    }

    @Override
    public GLGraphics getGraphics() {
       return glGraphics;
    }

    @Override
    public Audio getAudio() {
        return audio;
    }

    @Override
    public void setScreen(Screen screen) {
        if (screen == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Screen must not be null");

        this.screen.pause();
        this.screen.dispose();
        screen.resume();
        screen.update(0);
        this.screen = screen;
    }

    @Override
    public Screen getCurrentScreen() {
        return screen;
    }
}
```

Hope you guys can help me solve this problem ^^

**Edit1:**

LogCat:

```
12-01 17:14:35.329: E/chromium(9767): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:190: [1201/171435:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(190)] StatHub::Init - App com.example.jumper isn't supported.
12-01 17:14:35.329: E/chromium(9767): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:190: [1201/171435:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(190)] StatHub::Init - App com.example.jumper isn't supported.
12-01 17:14:35.990: V/BrowserManagement(9767):  PageLoadFinished
12-01 17:14:36.000: V/BrowserManagement(9767): WebviewLoaded
12-01 17:14:36.040: I/Ads(9767): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
12-01 17:14:36.040: I/Ads(9767): Ad finished loading.
12-01 17:14:36.130: D/BrowserManagement(9767): Destroy: unregister BatIntent
12-01 17:14:36.130: D/BrowserManagement(9767): Destroy: unregister BatIntent
12-01 17:14:37.722: D/BrowserManagement(9767): BatIntent Received: 2
12-01 17:14:38.012: D/BrowserManagement(9767): Callstate:0
12-01 17:14:38.012: D/BrowserManagement(9767): ConMgr If:null
12-01 17:14:38.012: E/BrowserManagement(9767): GoDormant p.interface null
12-01 17:14:43.477: V/BrowserManagement(9767): ViewTouched
12-01 17:14:43.487: V/BrowserManagement(9767): ViewTouched
12-01 17:14:43.497: V/BrowserManagement(9767): ViewTouched
12-01 17:14:43.507: V/BrowserManagement(9767): ViewTouched
12-01 17:14:43.527: V/BrowserManagement(9767): ViewTouched
12-01 17:14:43.547: V/BrowserManagement(9767): ViewTouched
12-01 17:14:43.547: V/BrowserManagement(9767): ViewFocusChanged
12-01 17:14:43.918: E/Ads(9767): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: attributionClick is not defined (http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/gma:1)
12-01 17:14:43.918: E/Web Console(9767): Uncaught ReferenceError: attributionClick is not defined at http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/gma:1
12-01 17:14:44.178: D/memalloc(9767): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x4cd46000 size:16580608 offset:15810560
12-01 17:14:44.178: D/memalloc(9767): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x4e6a5000 size:14266368 offset:13496320
12-01 17:14:44.178: D/memalloc(9767): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x4a5ba000 size:3842048 offset:3072000
12-01 17:14:44.178: D/MediaPlayer(9767): pause() mUri is null
12-01 17:14:44.208: I/Ads(9767): Ad opening.
12-01 17:14:44.268: I/Ads(9767): Ad leaving application.
12-01 17:14:44.628: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(9767): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
12-01 17:14:44.638: D/memalloc(9767): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x50336000 size:21626880 offset:20090880 fd:105
12-01 17:14:44.699: D/memalloc(9767): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x50336000 size:21626880 offset:20090880
12-01 17:14:44.709: D/memalloc(9767): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x4bd7a000 size:13496320 offset:11960320
12-01 17:14:44.709: D/memalloc(9767): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x49b87000 size:7352320 offset:5816320
12-01 17:14:44.719: D/memalloc(9767): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x4de2b000 size:8888320 offset:7352320
12-01 17:14:45.950: E/ActivityThread(9767): Activity com.example.jumper.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.gms.common.b@414f9420 that was originally bound here
12-01 17:14:45.950: E/ActivityThread(9767): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.example.jumper.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.gms.common.b@414f9420 that was originally bound here
12-01 17:14:45.950: E/ActivityThread(9767):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:936)
12-01 17:14:45.950: E/ActivityThread(9767):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:830)
12-01 17:14:45.950: E/ActivityThread(9767):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1129)
12-01 17:14:45.950: E/ActivityThread(9767):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:370)
12-01 17:14:45.950: E/ActivityThread(9767):     at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.b(SourceFile:330)
12-01 17:14:45.950: E/ActivityThread(9767):     at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.a(SourceFile:187)
12-01 17:14:45.950: E/ActivityThread(9767):     at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.a(SourceFile:173)
12-01 17:14:45.950: E/ActivityThread(9767):     at com.google.android.a.u.a(SourceFile:79)
12-01 17:14:45.950: E/ActivityThread(9767):     at com.google.android.a.u.doInBackground(SourceFile:75)
12-01 17:14:45.950: E/ActivityThread(9767):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
12-01 17:14:45.950: E/ActivityThread(9767):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-01 17:14:45.950: E/ActivityThread(9767):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-01 17:14:45.950: E/ActivityThread(9767):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
12-01 17:14:45.950: E/ActivityThread(9767):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-01 17:14:45.950: E/ActivityThread(9767):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-01 17:14:45.950: E/ActivityThread(9767):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-01 17:14:46.490: I/Ads(9767): Starting ad request.
12-01 17:14:56.510: A/libc(9767): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x0000010d (code=0)
12-01 17:15:16.640: I/AdvertisingIdClient(9767): AdvertisingIdClient unbindService failed.
12-01 17:15:16.640: I/AdvertisingIdClient(9767): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.common.b@414f9420
12-01 17:15:16.640: I/AdvertisingIdClient(9767):    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:888)
12-01 17:15:16.640: I/AdvertisingIdClient(9767):    at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1159)
12-01 17:15:16.640: I/AdvertisingIdClient(9767):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:375)
12-01 17:15:16.640: I/AdvertisingIdClient(9767):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.c(SourceFile:275)
12-01 17:15:16.640: I/AdvertisingIdClient(9767):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.b.c(SourceFile:100)
12-01 17:15:16.640: I/AdvertisingIdClient(9767):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.b.run(SourceFile:110)
12-01 17:15:46.719: W/Ads(9767): Timed out waiting for ad response.
12-01 17:15:56.989: W/dalvikvm(9892): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 180: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setPriority (I)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
12-01 17:15:57.189: W/dalvikvm(9892): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3091: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.getDefaultUserAgent (Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/lang/String;
12-01 17:15:57.239: W/dalvikvm(9892): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 156: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setPriority (I)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
12-01 17:15:57.269: D/WebSettings(9892): mDataPath: /data/data/com.example.jumper
12-01 17:15:57.329: I/Ads(9892): Starting ad request.
12-01 17:15:57.429: D/BrowserManagement(9892): BatIntent Received: 2
12-01 17:15:57.480: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(9892): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
12-01 17:15:57.480: D/memalloc(9892): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x4be94000 size:7352320 offset:5816320 fd:83
12-01 17:15:57.550: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(9892): <ConfigWindowMatch:2101>: Format RGB_565.
12-01 17:15:57.560: D/memalloc(9892): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x4c784000 size:16580608 offset:15810560 fd:89
12-01 17:15:57.630: D/memalloc(9892): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x4d950000 size:8888320 offset:7352320 fd:93
12-01 17:15:57.680: D/memalloc(9892): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x4e2ca000 size:10424320 offset:8888320 fd:96
12-01 17:15:57.780: D/BrowserManagement(9892): Destroy: unregister BatIntent
12-01 17:15:57.780: D/BrowserManagement(9892): Destroy: unregister BatIntent
12-01 17:15:58.020: V/android_drm_DrmManagerClient(9892): initialize - Enter
12-01 17:15:58.090: V/android_drm_DrmManagerClient(9892): initialize - Exit
12-01 17:15:58.090: V/android_drm_DrmManagerClient(9892): canHandleFd - Enter fd=87
12-01 17:15:58.090: V/android_drm_DrmManagerClient(9892): canHandle - Exit [fd=87] [result=0]
12-01 17:15:58.150: D/MediaPlayer(9892): processDrmFile
12-01 17:15:58.150: V/android_drm_DrmManagerClient(9892): canHandleFd - Enter fd=87
12-01 17:15:58.150: V/android_drm_DrmManagerClient(9892): canHandle - Exit [fd=87] [result=0]
12-01 17:15:58.150: D/MediaPlayer(9892): start() mUri is null
12-01 17:15:58.571: D/memalloc(9892): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x4a0b7000 size:3842048 offset:3072000 fd:109
12-01 17:15:58.581: D/memalloc(9892): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x4f232000 size:11194368 offset:10424320 fd:112
```

Comment: Could you please post your stack trace so that your the specific bug could be pointed out?